# Showing uniqueness of an intersection.

Tags: calculus

Assume that we have two differentiable functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is monotonically increasing, $f'>0$ and $g$ is monotonically decreasing, $g'<0$. We can prove that a intersection exists from the intermediate value theorem but I'm struggling to show the intersection is unique. My attempt is as follows.

Assume that $f=g$ at $x_1$ and $x_2$ where $x_1\neq x_2$. So $f(x_1)=g(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)=g(x_2)$. Let $x_2>x_1$, then $f(x_2)>f(x_1)=g(x_1)>g(x_2)$ using $f'>0$ and $g'<0$. Thus we can conclude that $f(x_2)\neq g(x_2)$, a contradiction.

The same applies to the case $x_2<x_1$.

Is this all that's required? If not, any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Also I guess differentiability isn't needed just monotonicity and continuity.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: I also think it is fine, but also concise and accurate. Well done. May be you should write "Assume WLOG that $x_2>x_1$" instead of "let". And yes, strict monotonicty and continuity is enough.